# How to Convert Word to a set number

Tags: java, string, int

Hello I was wondering how do I convert a word like "Hero" into a given number?

```
if(Hero.equalsIgnoreCase("Steve")) {
        // turns string hero into Steve Attack value

    }
    else if(Hero.equalsIgnoreCase("Akiro")) {
        // turns string hero into Akiro Attack value

    }
    else if (Hero.equalsIgnoreCase("Big Willie")) {
        // turns string hero into Big WIllie Attack Value

    }
    else if (Hero.equalsIgnoreCase("Shourya")) {
        // turns hero into Shourya Attack value

    }
```

Comment: What is the number you want to get out of it? Where does it come from (or how is it calculated) ? Does the user provide the number? After it is converted, what should happen? should it print to the console....? Write to a file....? More details are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just define a method that will use `switch` statement to check the name:

```java
public int getHeroAttackValue(String heroName) {
    switch (heroName.toLowerCase()) {
        case "steve": {
            return /* Steve attack power */;
        }
        case "akiro": {
            return /* Akiro attack power */;
        }
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Or you can create a HashMap that maps hero name to its attack power:

```java
HashMap<String, Integer> heroPowerMap = new HashMap<>();
heroPowerMap.put("Steve", steveAttackPower);
// etc.
```

then you can use:

```java
int steveAttackPower = heroPowerMap.get("Steve");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of going about this.

The easiest (and most OOP) would be to simply create a class `Hero` and include a field for damage, as such:

```
public class Hero {
    String name;
    int attackDamage;
}
```

Then, in your code, you would:

1. Create a list of heroes
2. Search through that list to find the one with a matching name.
3. Return their attack damage.

For example:

```
List<Hero> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(...);  // create a few heroes and add them to the list
...

String name = "hero name";

// now search for a hero and return their attack damage
int damage = list.stream()  // convert into a stream for easier searching
   .filter(hero -> hero.name.equalsIgnoreCase(name))  // find only heroes with the correct name
   .map(hero -> hero.attackDamage)  // get damage
   .findFirst()  // check if they exist
   .orElse(-1);  // return -1 if no hero found
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like a `HashMap`, with the names as keys and the powers as values.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> attackPowerMap = new HashMap<>();
attackPowerMap.put("Steve", 10);
```

And retrieve values with

```
int power = attackPowerMap.get("Steve") //Returns 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper way will be to use an Enum like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(HERO.Akiro.getValue());
  }

  private enum HERO {
    Steve(1),
    Akiro(2),
    BigWillie(3),
    Shourya(4);

    private final int value;
    HERO(final int newValue) {
      value = newValue;
    }
    public int getValue() { return value; }
  }
```

Treat immutable String literals as enum.